# Factorization special number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

Can a number $n=p_1\times p_2\times \dots\times p_k+1$ where $p_1, p_2,..., p_k$ are primes, be easily factorized? (the $k$ primes are known)

Comment: If there would be an easy way, then for example Collatz conjecture would be "easy" ... but at least you know $p_i \nmid n$. Btw I think you are using $n$ in two different meanings (number of primes and resulting number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If such a number could be easily factorised, then factorising $n$ would be as easy as factorising $n-1$. Which would be as easy as factorising $n-2$. And so on. So all you would have to do would be find a number $n-k$ that you can factorise, for some reasonably small $k$, and you could leapfrog your way to a factorisation of $n$.

While not conclusive, this argument suggests, to me at least, that such a number can't be easily factorised.

Comment: How do you obtain the factorization of $n+1$ from the factorization of $n$?

Comment: typically you wouldn't be able to in any simple way.

Comment: @mip: That is equivalent to what your question is positing: given the factorisation $p_1\times p_2\times \dots\times p_k$ of an integer $m$, can we factorise $n = m+1$?

Comment: I see, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. Until we know one of the primes is 2 or not, we can't tell if this value is even or odd. Until we know if 3 is one of the primes, or an odd number of the primes are 2 mod 3, we can't tell if 3 is a factor. Unless an odd number of primes are 3 mod 4, your value won't be divisible by 4. etc. But that's in effect trial division. Also it can be prime.  $2\cdot 3+1=7$ as an example.